# Handling Broken Download

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ipod

I have designed an application which will download some data from the server, and all is working fine if there is no network issue. However if there is some network fluctuation during download some data will not be downloaded and the app will crash.
Here I need some help from you guys. Is it possible for me to write a separate code to handle such situation and re-download the entire data by deleting the incomplete downloaded data.
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Try posting some code of what you are currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you can do that.
There are two situation 
1. Network not available.
    - -> To fix this you have to use "Rechability" sample code(Provided by Apple). Before start downloading you have to check for internet availability.
    - ->Or if you are not checking for internet rechability then you will got error code(404) in delegate method of NSURL connection: 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response

2. Network Fluctuation.
    Here I mean in between downloading if network fluctuate. Then it will call below method
 
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error

You can handle all the things inside this method

Answer (score 0):

When there is any network fluctuation or similar problem, you should get a HTTP error code if you are using NSURLConnection or any other network APIs. You could use that to delete the incomplete downloaded data and inform controller code so it could decide if to redownload etc.

Comment: Thank you very much Aditya Kumar Pandey for your reply. But I'm downloading different files in different classes of my application. And I just want to know if I can write this code in separate class, and handle all the downloads from this class. If so, then whether single function is enough and what must be its arguments and return type.

Answer (score 0):

Aditya is right. Assume that you are using NSURLConnection If your connection breaks you can read the response code using the following delegate method,

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {
     NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
     int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
}
```

and you could proceed with stopping the connection and deleting your unfinished download data.

---

Updated answer for the comment.

If you are using different connections in different classes you should have this implemented in each of the classes. In my opinion you should have a design like in which a particular class will handle all connection related tasks. (May be it won't suit your requirement). But for your current design you should use this in all your classes.

Comment: Thank you very much ElanthiraiyanS for your quick reply. But I'm downloading different files in different classes of my application. And I just want to know if I can write this code in separate class, and handle all the downloads from this class. If so, then whether single function is enough and what must be its arguments and return type.